# Cloned datarow is always empty

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm using this function to split my data table to smaller data tables, and the cloned rows always empty, why?

```
public static List<DataTable> SplitDataTable(DataTable originalTable, int batchSize)
{
    List<DataTable> partitions = new List<DataTable>(); 
    int i=0;
    foreach (DataRow row in originalTable.Rows)
    {
        int cell = i / batchSize;
        if (partitions.Count < cell+1 ||  partitions[cell] == null)
        {
            partitions.Add( new DataTable());
        }
        partitions[cell].ImportRow(row);                
        i++;
    }
    return partitions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation for the ImportRow() metho](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx)d, these two excerpts stand out to me:

> If the DataRow that is passed as a parameter is in a detached state, it is ignored, and no exception is thrown.

and

> If the new row violates a Constraint it won’t be added to the data table.